# Are Swift's embedded dylibs still required in macOS apps?

Tags: macos, xcode, swift

The Swift 5 release notes say:

> Swift apps no longer include dynamically linked libraries for the Swift standard library and Swift SDK overlays in build variants for devices running iOS 12.2, watchOS 5.2, and tvOS 12.2.

But there is no mention of macOS in the same context.

Do Mac applications written in Swift 5 still need to embed those 15 Swift dylibs (libswiftCore.dylib, libswiftFoundation.dylib, etc) consuming 11MB? It appears that, by default, Xcode 10.2 still embeds them.

Answer (score 4):

No, they do not. However, you need to target macOS 10.14.4 to take advantage of this.

Comment: I didn't know you could refine the target OS to the third place.  It certainly works, reducing my app size from >11MB to <900KB !

Answer (score 0):

It's still a really good idea to include them so that you have compatibility with more devices.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. If you have the answer, consider [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/360031/edit) the post and mention it.